# Schedule an entire file with ScheduledAudioFileRegion

Tags: ios, macos, swift, core-audio, audiounit

In Objective-C we filled out the *ScheduledAudioFileRegion* struct like so:

```
ScheduledAudioFileRegion playRegion;
playRegion.mTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
playRegion.mTimeStamp.mSampleTime = 0;
playRegion.mCompletionProc = NULL;
playRegion.mCompletionProcUserData = NULL;
playRegion.mAudioFile = audioFileID;
playRegion.mLoopCount = 0;
playRegion.mStartFrame = 0;
playRegion.mFramesToPlay = -1;
```

with the `mFramesToPlay` set to -1 to tell it to play the entire file.

Swift will not allow me to set a UInt32 to -1. So how do I tell it to play the entire file?

I know this is not the only place that a negative value for a UInt32 was used as a flag in Obj-C, but it's the first time I've run into it.

Comment: Have you tried `LONG_MAX` or `ULONG_MAX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mFramesToPlay` is a `UInt32`, and Swift does not implicitly convert
between signed and unsigned integers. You could write

```
playRegion.mFramesToPlay = UInt32(bitPattern: -1)
```

or just

```
playRegion.mFramesToPlay = UInt32.max
```